# sqlalchemy и ForeignKey получение при запросе только одного

Tags: python-3.6, sqlalchemy

Есть модель в которой два столбца привязаны к id пользователя

```
class Marriage(Base):
"""
Модель отвечает за браки
"""
__tablename__ = 'Marriage'

marriage_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
# пользователи в браке
marriage_user_first = Column('First_user', ForeignKey(
    User.user_id, onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"))
marriage_user_second = Column('Second_user', ForeignKey(
    User.user_id, onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
```

Каким образом можно воспользоваться следующим вариантом?

```
# получаем пару
brak = session.query(Marriage).get(
marriage_user_first=message.from_id)
```

Вылетает с ошибкой

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'marriage_user_first'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `marriage_user_first` не является первичным ключом, поэтому `get` здесь бесполезен.

Используйте `filter_by` в сочетании с `first`:

```
brak = (session
        .query(Marriage)
        .filter_by(marriage_user_first=message.from_id)
        ).first()
```